# Find the correct row for didSelectRow after moveRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a TableView in which every row has a segue to another Storyboard.
I want that the user can reorder the rows as he want to. 
But this crashes the segues to the other Storyboards. How can I connect the "case 0: .., case 1:..." to the initially indexPath.row?

Here are the central parts of my code so far:

```
let languageStore = UserDefaults(suiteName: "LanguageSelect")
var languages = [String]()

func initializelanguageList() {
    if let defaults = self.languageStore?.array(forKey: "languages") as? [String] {
        self.languages = defaults
    } else {
        self.languages = ["Español", "Español", "English", "English", "Deutsch", "Deutsch"]
        self.languageStore?.set(self.languages, forKey: "languages")
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let language = self.languages.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    self.languages.insert(language, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    self.languageStore?.set(self.languages, forKey: "languages")
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return languages.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.languages[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    print(indexPath.row)
    let row = indexPath.row
    switch(row){
    case 0:  
        let ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "firstSBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstTabBar")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: false)

    case 1:            
        let ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "secondSBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondTabBar")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: false)

   case 2:...

        break
    default: break   
    }     
}}
```

At first I had the TableView with the case switch, which worked. But now I tried something new for me with the CanMoveRow possibility. Which chrashes the segues. I understand now, that the problem is in the switch. I have to track the indices.

**EDIT**
solved by the help of Matic Oblak:

```
let languageStore = UserDefaults(suiteName: "LanguageSelect")
var languages = [(name: String, index: Int)]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initializelanguageList()
}

func initializelanguageList() {
    if let defaults = self.languageStore?.array(forKey: "languages1.0") as? [String] {
        self.languages = defaults.enumerated().map { (name: $1, index: $0) }
    } else {
        let languages = ["Español1", "Español2", "English1", "English2", "Deutsch1", "Deutsch1"]
        self.languages = languages.enumerated().map { (name: $1, index: $0) }
        self.languageStore?.set(languages, forKey: "languages1.0")
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let language = self.languages.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    self.languages.insert(language, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    self.languageStore?.set(self.languages.map { $0.name }, forKey: "languages1.0")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return languages.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
         cell.textLabel?.text = self.languages[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

    switch(self.languages[indexPath.row].index){
case 0:  
    let ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "espanol1SBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "espanol1TabBar")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: false)

case 1:            
    let ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "espanol2SBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "espanol2TabBar")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: false)

 case 2:...

    }



}
```

Comment: What's the connection between the data shown in the cell and the storyboard you need to show?

Comment: I had to cut my code. Now I could add some more, I hope you can understand. I just want that the user can reorder the languages, but the segues didn't work correctly after reordering.

Comment: No, you have not answered my question. You build a dynamic list of languages but you seem to have a hardcoded list of storyboards. Why?

Comment: That's because you haven't removed the object from the source before inserting it to a new destination.  Inevitably, the app will crash since the cellForRowAt method doesn't have a sufficient number of rows to show.

Comment: @rmaddy till this point it worked well, now that I want to use the CanMoveRow possibility I have to learn something new. But in my search so far, I couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you left some important part of your code which is responsible for the mess you are having. Why for instance would you have a switch statement in `didSelectRowAt`? It should look like the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    let ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "firstSBoard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstTabBar")
    ViewController.language = languages[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: false)
}
```

As you can see in this case your array is the only source of truth and order should never effect your result.

But if you do really need to track those indices you can simply change your structure to have the following:

```
var languages = [(name: String, index: Int)]()
```

then

```
self.languages = defaults.enumerated.map { (name: $1, index: $0) }

cell.textLabel?.text = self.languages[indexPath.row].name

switch(self.languages[indexPath.row].index){
    case 0:
```

**EDIT: Adding the full code to map languages:**

```
func initializelanguageList() {
    if let defaults = self.languageStore?.array(forKey: "languages") as? [String] {
        self.languages = defaults.enumerated.map { (name: $1, index: $0) }
    } else {
        let languages = ["Español", "Español", "English", "English", "Deutsch", "Deutsch"]
        self.languages = languages.enumerated.map { (name: $1, index: $0) }
        self.languageStore?.set(languages, forKey: "languages")
    }
}
```

Or if in any case you need to transform them back you would do:

```
self.languageStore?.set(self.languages.map { $0.name }, forKey: "languages")
```

Comment: yes, I think I have to track the indices!
so I put a let name = ["Español", ...] on top, but what should I do in the else {...} in the func initializelanguageList() ?

Comment: @LarsB Please check the edit

Comment: Thanks! But for the enumerated parts I got the error: "Method 'enumerated' was used as a property; add () to call it" so I have to put in the ()
The simulator starts with this configuration and I can use the segues. But when I reorder the cells, the simulator crashes with the error:  Attempt to set a non-property-list object (...) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key languages

Comment: @LarsB You are most likely still calling `self.languages` directly instead of mapping it. Please check the last line I have written.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I think now I understand. But one more small thing: When I change the names of the languages, I have to delete the app first to see the changes. Would the user have the same problem after getting an update over the App Store, when I change the names in a future version?

Comment: @LarsB I am not sure I understand your question. But if I do then the what you are talking about is you need to change those "default" languages. To do that I suggest you simply change the key name for user defaults when you add/change languages. But make sure you change it EVERYWHERE you use it (use static variable or something). So basically when you create a new iteration of languages simply change "languages" to for instance "languages1.0", then to "languages1.1" or however you wish to index them.

Comment: Hi, thanks, to change the keyname works great! But I realized that I got a chaos with the segues: When I first open the app, everything works fine. For example: I click on the first cell "Espanol1" and the app shows me the ViewController with the "espanol1tabbar". I can go back, move the first cell to the 4th position and can click on this cell on the 4.th position and it will show me the VC with the espanol1tabbar. Everything fine.

Comment: But when I close the app and start it a second time, I got chaos: The titles of the cells are as I left them. In our example I left the espanol1 on the 4.th position. The title is there, but when I click on it, I will see the VC of english2! And I only can come to the VC of espanol1 when I click on the first cell... Seems to me that the title is saved, but the indexposition not (or only in the moment of first use)